# C++ Compiler Error C2751 - What exactly causes it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, function-parameter

I am wrestling with the [C2751](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w01cz7z.aspx) compiler error and don't quite understand what exactly causes it. The following little code produces the error:

```
#include <iostream>  

class A {
public:
    A () { std::cout << "A constructed" << std::endl; };
    static A giveA () { return A (); }
};

class  B {
public:
    B (const A& a) { std::cout << "B constructed" << std::endl; }
};


int main () {

    B b1 = B (A::giveA ()); // works
    B b2 (B (A::giveA ())); // C2751
    B b3 (A::giveA ()); // works

}
```

Compiler output:

`consoleapplication1.cpp(21): error C2751: 'A::giveA': the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified`

Why can't I call the constructor explicitly for `b2`?

Comment: What compiler do you use? Because gcc 5.4 builds with code without any issues.

Comment: @knst he's using MSVC (see C2751 link)

Comment: @knst It doesn't compile with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UajAZ5zfaV8QWmZD) either.

Comment: From the message, VC++ thinks you are declaring a function; this is some variation of the usual vexing parse problem. Add parentheses liberally and it should go away.

Comment: This is the kind of question that makes you face palm real hard when you find out why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the problem of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Compiling under clang gives a full diagnostic:

```
<source>:18:17: error: parameter declarator cannot be qualified
    B b2 (B (A::giveA ())); // C2751
             ~~~^

<source>:18:10: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    B b2 (B (A::giveA ())); // C2751
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:18:11: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
    B b2 (B (A::giveA ())); // C2751
          ^
          (              )
1 warning and 1 error generated.
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

Doing as the compiler suggests fixes it:

```
B b2 ((B (A::giveA ()))); // no error
```

Comment: Thank you, the clang output was really helpful. May I ask why is it "allowed" to declare a function within a function? I can't really think of a situation where I would want to do that.

Comment: imagine how you might write: "`b2` is a function that takes a function which returns a `B` and takes a function which returns a `A::giveA` while taking no arguments"

Answer (score 2):

That particular instruction is ambiguous; the way you stated it it may be either a function declaration or a variable definition.

Using extra parentheses should help - it gets unambiguous since you can't declare/call a function with double parentheses:

```
B b1 = B( A::giveA () ); // works
B b2(( B( A::giveA() ) )); // works for me
B b3( A::giveA() ); // works
```

Also see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: "There's no c-tor/method `B( B b )`, and the compiler thinks you're calling it." The compiler _knows_ that you can't declare such a constructor. It won't think you're calling it (unless it has some bug).

Answer (score 2):

```
B b2 (B (A::giveA ()));
```

Even if you had a copy constructor of `B` class, you'd still get this error since the line above conforms to the grammar rules of a function-declaration. Having parenthesis around `B(A::give())` solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the ol' problem of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

This line here

```
B b2 (B (A::giveA ())); // C2751
```

is interpreted as a function `b2` returning `B` and taking a parameter called `A::giveA` of function type `B()`. The C2751 error is caused by the invalid name `A::giveA`: you cannot use a qualified name as a parameter name.

To copy a temporary `B` object into `b2` (which I believe is your intention) you can add more brackets

```
B b2 (( B (A::giveA ()) ));
```

or use braces (so long as there isn't a constructor that accepts initialiser lists containing a type convertible to type `B`)

```
B b2 {B (A::giveA())};
```