# Can not instantiate class as LHS value with qualified enum as argument (C++ VS2015)

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, most-vexing-parse

I'm a little bit supprised as i see this compilation error;

Here is the example:

```
class A
{
public:
  enum eA { eA1, eA2 };

  class B
  {
  public:
    B(eA e, int i = 0);
  };

  A(const B &b);
};

A::A(const B &b)
{
}

A::B::B(eA e, int i /*= 0*/)
{
}

int main()
{
  A::B b(A::eA1);        // OK
  A a0(b);               // OK
  A a1(A::B(A::eA1, 0)); // OK
  A a2(A::B(A::eA2));    //error C2751: 'A::eA2': the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified
  return 0;
}
```

As pointed in comments, `A a2(A::B(A::eA2));` doesn't compile. Why?
I'm not asking how to compile it. Why it doesn't compile?

It compiles, if first parameter type of class-`B` is not from class-`A`. for example with `int` it compiles.

Comment: I would say this is a Most Vexing Parse issue  (your error line attempts to declare `a2` as a function returning `A` taking one parameter of typ `A::B` named `A::eA2`) ... although not sure yet whether the presence of `A::` should make it fall back to being an object declaration, versus giving a declaration syntax error

Comment: This should not be marked as duplicate as this is valid code that [compiles file with gcc](http://ideone.com/rXmavE). This seem to be VS bug of some kind. As a workaround you can use uniform initialization when constructing variables like this: `A a2{A::B(A::eA2)};`

Comment: @M.M I was reading right now another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045257/c-compiler-error-c2751-what-exactly-causes-it)  which looks like my problem, but i still don't understand, why it compiles if the type of first B-Constructor is int.

Comment: @M.M if B-Constructor were `B(int i1, int i2 = 0);`, than it compiles `A a(A::B(1));`

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz you may want to open [Microsoft connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) as this problem seems to be present in VS2017 as well.

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz `1` is not an identifier so there is no ambiguity

Comment: @VTT I think this is not a compiler bug,  so reporting a bug would be a bad idea

Comment: @VVT you are right, but i think the question is not duplicate as marked here. the question can be closed but it is not an absolute duplicate.

Comment: reopened, although it is a MVP issue this is more complicated than what is answered in the suggested duplicate, which does not cover the case of the innermost id-expression containing `::`

Comment: @M.M when it is not a bug, how does it compiles with gcc? Or do we have any warning with gcc, instead of error?

Comment: gcc might be bugged

Comment: @M.M. Well, since gcc compiles it fine and VS not then it is a bug in either gcc or VS (and I typically tend to blame VS).

Comment: Added MVP/LL tags and removed inner-class tag; the inner class is a red herring and you could reproduce the same issue with B not being an inner class. (The enum must still be inside A though for this particular case)

Comment: @M.M Should we also correct the question title?

Comment: It would be fine with or without IMO , maybe you could instead mention "qualified enum as argument" instead of "default parameter" (which is another red herring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Most Vexing Parse issue. The [canonical case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) would be:

```
T t( U(x) );
```

where T and U are previously known to be type names. This could be parsed in two valid ways:

- a declaration of `t` as an object of type `T`, with the initializer being the expression `U(x)`, a function-style cast of the variable `x` to a temporary `U`
- a declaration of `t` as a function returning `T`, with 1 parameter of type `U` and name `x`; and there are redundant parentheses around `x`. (Declarators may be parenthesized).

The text in the Standard for disambiguating is in [dcl.ambig.res]/1. What it says is that parsing this code hinges on whether `U(x)` would be a declaration or an expression, and then refers to [stmt.ambig].

In [stmt.ambig]/2 there is a clarifying example. I won't reproduce the full example here (you can look it up in a standards draft) but the accompanying text is:

> If the statement cannot **syntactically** be a declaration, there is no ambiguity
>
> [...] This is of course ill-formed for semantic reasons, but that does not affect the syntactic analysis. In those cases the statement is a declaration.

What this is trying to say is that if the code can be matched to the rules in the language grammar for a declaration, then it is a declaration, even if the code subsequently falls foul of a semantic rule.

---

Looking at your variation now, where the inner code is (simplified) `U(A::e)` where `e` is an enumerator in the scope of `A`.

I believe this code *does* still match the grammar rule for a declaration. See [dcl.decl]/4 grammar specification (selected parts):

> *noptr-declarator: declarator-id attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *declarator-id: ...<sub>opt</sub> id-expression*

and *id-expression* can be *qualified-id* or *unqualified-id*, and finally, `A::e` is a *qualified-id*.

Even though there is a semantic rule [dcl.meaning]/1 that the *declarator-id* can only be a *qualified-id* in certain contexts, excluding this case,  that's not a grammar rule.

So I would say VC is correct to reject the code.

---

To fix the code, assuming the intent is for `a2` to be an object declaration, you can use the same techniques as mentioned on the canonical MVP thread:

```
A a2{A::B(A::eA2)};    // braced initialization

A a2((A::B(A::eA2)));  // function declarations can't have extra parentheses around the entire parameter declaration, so this cannot be a function declaration
```

Comment: Great answer. Would be even better if you also show the two ways of fixing it (brace-initialization and additional parentheses).

Comment: @SebastianRedl added